# Power BI down filters have old data after data refresh

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

We have a power bi report where we have enabled data refresh based on some parameters. One of the problem we have faced is that if a value is selected in a drop down list and then the data is refreshed based on another parameter, the values in the dropdown should complete change as the old selections are no more valid. However, the dropdown still contains old selection

However, as soon as you click on the dropdown, you will see completely new changed value and selecting any other those value will remove the old value from the dropbox and it completely disappears

Can someone please explain why the old selection is still there in the dropdown list even though the data is complete changed with new values in the dropdown list?

Comment: Sounds like PBI is caching the value because it is in a selected state.  You might try using a bookmark to reset that values in the slicers.

Comment: Do you have visual interactions disabled between the "dropdowns"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: When every dateset is bringing a different set of values to the dropdown list, how can I reset the selection through the bookmark because bookmark also saves a specific selection right?